# Woocommerce Update All Product SKU

Tags: woocommerce

Is there any way to update all of my products SKU? I have a space in my SKU. Cant figure it out how to delete it from all. Its like "ABC 123". Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to export all products as .csv (On the "All Products" Page, there should be an export button next to the "add new" button.).

Add ID and SKU to the export columns and download the file -> Open the file in excel, mark the SKU column -> find and replace the space with nothing -> replace all, then save the file as .csv

Now you can upload the file via the Import button next to the add new button. Tick the "update product" checkbox.

Now the importer will check if the ID exists,and update the SKU accordingly (ideally this works, I have not tried this, it might fail because SKU is also checked).
Make sure to first try it with one product only, or alternatively on a staging site.

If that doesn't work, you could make a Python script to update the SKU via the woocommerce API (https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#products). If it's worth the effort in contrast to changing the sku manually depends on the amount of products you have of course.

A plugin that allows bulk editing of products could be a solution too.